# How to fix excessive fan usage and possibly false CPU temperature readings on Asus ROG laptop?

Tags: laptop, bios, fan, cooling, asus-laptop

Problem started about 4 weeks ago and I suspect it was caused by a bad Windows 10 update that broke something.

Symptoms:

- Fan comes on full blast almost immediately after booting up and stays that way almost constantly
- CPU temperature is reported as abnormally but not dangerously hot while idling. I checked in the BIOS and the fan is running at 5000-7000 RPM while the CPU temperature is around 42-48 degrees (C, not F). The temperature readouts are a bit suspicious considering it's not a particularly fast CPU (2.2 GHz, no overclocking). Even if the temperature readouts are correct, 48 degrees isn't dangerous for a CPU and should not cause the fan to do this.
- Air coming out of the fan outlet vents is cold when this happens, indicating the temperature readings are probably false and the fan overboost is spurious.
- Asus ROG "Gaming Center" (monitor tool for CPU/GPU temperature and memory usage) shows CPU and GPU as "0", failing to detect temperature or memory usage for either.
- Fan comes on full blast when the computer is idling (CPU usage around 1-2%)
- GPU is running at 37 degrees C - nowhere near close to overheat

Attempted fixes so far (none of these fix the problem):

- Asus ROG "Gaming Center" control panel. There's no way to disable "Fan Overboost" (only options are "Auto" and "Overboost". Failure to display CPU/GPU or provide options to configure them doesn't help either
- Checking the BIOS for controls. There's supposed to be controls for fan speed in the BIOS but those are completely missing.
- Configure power settings to "Power Saver" and cooling policy to "Passive" (throttle the CPU before turning the fan up).
- Checked the computer with Malwarebytes Anti-Malware to make sure there isn't hidden crapware/malware that somehow uses a lot of CPU and hides from Task Manager. None found.
- Check Device Manager for driver updates on anything related to thermal management. Everything I found so far is up to date.

Laptop specifications via System Information:

- Operating system: Windows 10 Home version number 10.0.19043
- Computer model: Asus Strix GL504GM
- CPU: Intel Core i7-8750H CPU 2.2 GHz, 6 cores
- BIOS version: American Megatrends GL504GM.314 (timestamped August 10, 2021 - not out of date)

Comment: To prove the point that it is OS, try booting from USB, e.g. Ubuntu Live -- no need to install. If the problem persists, it's hardware, and if not, it's Windows. If it *is* Windows, try DISM and FSC, which might find te cause, or reinstalling Windows from ISO.

Comment: Every laptop I have ever dealt with, has always ended up having to be stripped to remove the fluff from between the heat sink blades which causes the fan to run fast..

Comment: Well I was able to rule out overheating or false temperature readouts. I reinstalled ROG Gaming Center and it displays the CPU temperature at 32 degrees C. Despite this, the fans are running at a nonsensical 5000-6000 RPM. By now, I'm sure the best solution is a manual fan speed limiter utility.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a cheep amazon 12V RGB hub with 10 ports.  It uses a SATA drive cable for power.  On a brand new install of windows to a new motherboard, new processor, old RMA and GPU (can't have every thing...).  The point is, stock Windows, zero software added, and the CPU is running at above the rating of the chip like 4.5 - 5 GHz while doing nothing. As reported by the OS probes that is.  I'm sure it is not running that pace. When looking with Asus utilities, one core is showing very high while the rest are basically idle. I don't have the BIOS set for anything beyond the rated speed but this is what I see.

Anyway, the whole thing is setup with water cooling so there is no single PWM fan connected to the CPU fan header.  That line is going to the hub and getting alternate power from SATA.  As soon as windows finished installing, the fans go ape sh*t. 100% full on.  Also, the coolant temp is hovering just above room temp. While on BIOS or during install, no issue. The fans followed the BIOS settings to a T.

Rummaging around on the internet I found nothing (but this thread) that seemed similar.  Off chance I was moving some wires about and found that the 4 pin CPU header I have running to a two pin PWM input to the fan hub could be manipulated, and the fan speeds came back to normal.  Oddly this didn't matter during BIOS and install, but made a huge difference after Windows got involved.  Apparently the signal quality has some part in the behavior.  I found a way to get the wires situated that now works.  For the fans that is.  The CPU reporting is still way odd.  Still looking for solutions to that.

Anyway, hope this helps!

- Asus Crossfire VIII Hero Wifi (AM4 X570)
- AMD Ryzen 5950X (3.4Ghz w/o
  OC)
- EK-Quantum Velocity CPU Water Block
- EK-Quantum Kinetic TBE Reservoir/Pump
- Nvidia Geforce GTX 260 (My 1080Ti died and took old MB    with it)
- 32GB GSkill Trident DDR4 3200 2133 Mhz

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).